# How to determine if this is a field?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, discrete-mathematics, finite-fields

A finite subring $R$ of a field $V$ contains $1$ (so $1$ is an element of $R$).

The question is:
True or False: The ring $R$ *must* be a field.

I thought that if $R$ was a field it *had* to be a finite field in this case (because $R$ is a finite ring). And to be able to be a finite field, it should have
$$ |R| = p^n $$ 
With $p$ a prime and $n$ a natural number, but this doesn't *have* to be the case.

I could be wrong or what I'm saying could be insufficient to prove this right or wrong.

Please help ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** It is a finite integral domain.  Or else if you are not acquainted with the relevant theorem, the only issue is whether every non-zero element $a$ of $R$ has a (multiplicative)  inverse.

To show that it does, consider the powers of $a$. By finiteness, there must be integers $m$ and $n$, with $0\le m \lt n$ such that $a^m=a^n$. But then $a^{n-m}=1$. From this you should be able to show that some power of $a$ is the inverse of $a$.

**Remark:** You are right that if $R$ is a field (which it is) then $R$ will have $p^n$ elements for some prime $p$ and some positive integer $n$. However, that does not lead to a contradiction.

Comment: I will work with your first hint to try and find the answer, but about the remark, why not? That would mean that to be a finite field the subring R MUST have p^n elements.. If this does not lead to a contradiction, that would mean that this theorem also says that every subring of a field V with 1 as an element has by definition p^n elements?

Comment: @Spyral: If $R$ is finite and contains $1$, then indeed $R$ has size $p^n$ for some $n$. Thus the original field $V$ has characteristic $p$. But that's absolutely fine, there are many fields of characteristic $p$, including many infinite ones.

Comment: I do see that a^(n-m) immediately leads to a^-m being the inverse of a^n. But what I did not know was that if R is a finite ring there must be integers m and n such that $$ a^m = a^n $$ .. (I can't find this property in my syllabus).

Comment: Look at $a^1, a^2, a^3,a^4,\dots$ and so on forever. These are all in $R$. But $R$ is *finite*, so there must be repetition. Now suppose that $a^n=a^m$ wwhere $m \lt n$. since $a^n=a^{n-m}a^m$, we have $a^{n-m}=1$. Thus $a a^{n-m-1}=1$, and therefore $a^{n-m-1}$ is the inverse of $a$.

Answer (score 4):

Since $R$ is a finite subring, it is sufficient to check whether it is an integral domain, as every finite integral domain is a field.

Of course, a (sub)ring is an integral domain if it has no zero divisors.

Assume by contradiction that $R$ has zero divisors. Then, there are $a,b \in R$ such that $ab = 0$.

$V$ is a field, and so $V$ is an integral domain and has no zero divisors. Since $a,b \in R \subset V$, then $V$ has zero divisors, contradicting the statement that $V$ is a field.